# Spring JPA findBy two or conditions

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Need help with Spring JPA.  Say I want to find who checkout the car when gotten a traffic ticket.   So that `licenseNum` and

1. `citationDate` is greater than `checkoutDate` and `citationDate` is less than `returnDate`; or
2. `citationDate` is greater than `checkoutDate` and `returnDate` is `null`.

Currently,

```
List<SomeEntity> findByLicenseNumAndCheckOutDatetimeBeforeAndReturnDatetimeAfterOrReturnDatetimeIsNullOrderByIdDesc()
```

produces #1 correctly but produces all `licenseNum` with `returnDate` `null`.

How do I write spring JPA statement with 'or' statement correctly?

Comment: Spring Data [does not support nested/grouped constraints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage) with method names, therefore what you are looking for is not possible.

Comment: For usecases more complex that simple findByName, choose a **good, meaningful** name for your method, that doesn't take 80 characters, annotate it with Query, and write the JPQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually think of using a `Query` annotation where you can specify a custom query. Yon can choose a more meaningful method name and easy to maintain/change.